# android.database.cursor index out of bound of exception?

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to retrieve name and type of the contacts stored in phone, but getting this exception. I was getting the names before but getting exception

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested with a size of 10

when tried to retrieve name and type together. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
package application.test;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.util.Log;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String[] projection = new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};     
        String[] projection1=new String[]{Phone.TYPE};
        String[] projection2=new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID};

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        ContentResolver ncr=getContentResolver();
        ContentResolver icr=getContentResolver();

        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection,null, null, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        Cursor ncur=ncr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, projection1, null, null,null);
        Cursor icur = icr.query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection2,null, null, Contacts._ID + " ASC");

        if (cur.getCount() >0 && ncur.getCount()>0 && icur.getCount()>0) 
        {
            while (cur.moveToNext()&& ncur.moveToNext()&& icur.getCount()>0) 
            {

                String id = icur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String  type=ncur.getString(ncur.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));

                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
                {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, 
                                                                 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id}, null);     
                    Cursor typecur = ncr.query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null)          

                    while (pCur.moveToNext()&& typecur.moveToNext())
                    {

                        Log.d("names",name);
                        Log.d("types",type);
                        pCur.close();
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you make three separate cursors?

Comment: because using three different projections.I try using one but got compile time error.

Answer (score 8):

When u create a cursor before reading it. Move the cursor position to first.

```
while (cur.moveToNext()&& ncur.moveToNext()&& icur.getCount()>0) 

  /* move icur to first position then read */
  icur.moveFirst()
```

It must work

Comment: cur.moveToNext() will do this for you, it will act as cur.moveToFirst().

Answer (score 2):

You should not create three differents cursors and contextresolver, use the same, but make the conditions in the loop in order to get what you want, I'll give you a method I wrote myself.
This will give you all the contacts in your phone which has a phone number, you'll get the idea of to implements yours:

```
public ArrayList<Contact> getSMSContacts(Context context){
    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " asc");
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                Contact c = new Contact();
                c.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
                c.setName(name);
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String number = pCur.getString(
                            pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    c.setNumber(number);
                } 
                pCur.close();
                contacts.add(c);
            }
        }
    }
    cur.close();
    return contacts;
}
```

Comment: you are getting only contacts here which get stored in contacts column.For type it goes like  Cursor ncur=ncr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, projection1, null, null,null);as types get scored in Data column.same as contact_id get store in rawcontactid column.besides that I was getting runtimeexception using single cursor object and passing projection to it.

Comment: Like I told you, you'll get the idea watching my implementation, and btw it works fine! What do you mean by type? What is it that you want except the contacts name.

Comment: String type = pCur.getString(      pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));

Answer (score 1):

After days of search I have finally got the answers..type and name get stored in data table under DATA2 column thus I queried data.content_uri and got the index of DATA2 column and its just working fine...I am getting both name and type.